# Given we want to design the django polls application, sequentially how do we go about doing the BDD

Tags: python, django, tdd, cucumber, bdd

I come from the python/django background.

I have been reading about BDD, and why it is more awesome than TDD. But few of the doubts that came up to my mind was, what would be an ideal way to go about doing BDD? Does it rule out writing unittests? Does it rule out doing integration tests? I could not find an answer or an organized sequential path to implement BDD.

For designing a [django polls application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) via TDD, I would go as follows:

1. Write test for models, then make the tests pass.
2. Write test for forms, then make them pass.
3. Write test for views, then make them pass.
4. Write any other test for custom template tags and middlewares, and make them pass.
5. Keep on writing integration tests progressively, since the time I start writing views.

Based on my reading, what I could make out was, in case if I design a django polls application, the process that I will have to follow are the following:

1. Write scenarios in gherkin syntax
2. Write steps
3. In the steps probably use some assertions(unit), based on ui response(integration)
4. Not sure, what/how to do next or even part 3 is correct.

Please help me clear my confusion, and suggest a brief outline,

Please let me know, how do I go ahead. What would be a sequential approach to attempt BDD when we do the [django polls application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

(I hope this question, is not a subjective one, and SO is a good place to ask for it, if not don't kill me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While BDD encompasses some specific technical practices (like automation guided by scenarios, outside-in development, unit tests, ...), its main goal is to improve communication within a project (including non-technical stakeholders).

You start by gathering specifications - in the form of examples - by discussing with the stakeholders. This can be done in many ways, the most important thing here is to *talk*. Don't force them or yourself into writing gherkin-valid scenarios during those discussions. Just capture the expected *behaviour* along with the acceptance criteria (i.e. the constraints the system has to follow).

You'll then formalise the scenarios and - ideally - review them with a business person. This phase is interesting because it will validate your (and the teams's) comprehension of the specification. You often end up realising you made bad assumptions :)

When you've defined a bunch of specifications (features) and agreed upon their priorities, you can start the actual development process.

My usual way of working is something like this:

1. Run a scenario, see its first step undefined;
2. Add a step definition for that step;
3. Run again, see it fail because of missing implementation;
4. Write one unit test/spec for that missing system behaviour;
5. Run the test, see it fail;
6. Make it pass;
7. Refactor your code;
8. Run the scenario again

   - if a step is failing go to #4
   - else if a step is undefined, go to #2
   - else you're finished with this scenario, go to the next one :)

This is, basically, outside-in development. As you may have noticed steps 4 to 7 are the usual TDD cycle. One benefit of this workflow is your TDD cycle is properly guided: you don't have to think about what to do next. The actual next required behaviour is explicitly displayed to you thanks to the scenario failure stack trace.

Of course, this is *one way* of doing things. There's nothing written in stone and you can adapt things.